# Remove HTML5 validation from a number field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that has a number field with display: none;

This field is not marked as required but it does have min values. It also have a set value of 0 (until changed) that must stay this way.

This is the code of the input:

```
<input type="number" min="200" step="100" name="limit1" id="limit1" placeholder="amount" value="0" style="display: none;">
```

Is it possible to remove the html5 validation for this field?

I don't want to use novalidate on the entire form but only to disable this element's check.

Thanks.

Comment: change `type="hidden"`

Comment: So what must happen when the value changes from 0 to something else? And who does that? You (programmatically) or the user?

Comment: This field is hidden until another checkbox in the form is checked. Then it's value is changed to the value of min and it is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `novalidate` attribute on a form but that will remove validation on the entire form. For individual fields you could try temporarily changing their type to `text` or `hidden` when they're not supposed to be visible. These will retain the value but don't support attributes like `min`.

Comment: I know, I'm expanding my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `disabled` attribute

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the `oninvalid` attribute with a `return false`:

```
<input type="number" 
       min="200"  
       step="100" 
       name="limit1" 
       id="limit1" 
       placeholder="amount" 
       value="0" 
       oninvalid="return false" <!-- -->
       style="display: none;">
```

Comment: This one is almost true. It does stop the field from being checked, but still doesn't submit the form.

Comment: what's worse, the return false is actually the same as on submit return false for the whole form if the field fails validation. it's just that it's triggered before the onSubmit event of the form so it prevents the form submit event from ever triggering.